# Standard for accessiblity testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-design

As a Software Engineer I want to create software that contains accessibility for people with disabilities.

I've been making modifications so that [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS) correctly reads all the fields in my interface.

The Testers use JAWS to test accessibility, but I wonder if JAWS really is the baseline that we should be utilizing for screen reader accessibility?

If not, then which screen reader should we be using for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Accessibility In Mind (WEBAIM) project regularly publishes [statistics on popular screen readers](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/). Here are their findings as of July 2015:

***Screen Reader:*** *# of Respondents / % of Respondents*


**JAWS:** 743 / 30.2%
**ZoomText:** 545 / 22.2%
**Window-Eyes:** 508 / 20.7%
**NVDA:** 360 / 14.6%
**VoiceOver:** 188 / 7.6%
**System Access or System Access To Go:** 36 / 1.5%
**ChromeVox:** 8 / 0.3%
**Other:** 72 / 2.9%