# Free tools for Accessibility testing automation

Tags: automated-testing, open-source

I am trying to have hands on Accessibility automation testing. I would like to know if there are any best free tools available to start with?

I can see projects in the GIT hub but no information about which IDE to use to import the project?

Are there any free IDE available to import and  access the automation project?

Comment: I guess you've had a look through [W3C's Web Accessibility Evaluation Tools List](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/)? https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core and https://github.com/Tanaguru/Tanaguru for example?

Comment: You mean browser automation or be specific if something else.

Comment: @Rao browser automation for accessibility testing.

Comment: @Pri I think you are looking for IDE type think as you get the code. Just you need to configure it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse for import project .We can discuss on How to import project in Git by mail for further details.

Comment: @Sagar007 sorry if my question is unclear. I will edit it. I want to know about which IDE i can use to create accessibility tests. or which platform i can use to draft the tests. I am aware of cloning/importing the projects from github.

Comment: @Pri Thats nice. Still if you require any help regarding import and using project you can ask here. I have also same problems so. contact me as well.

Comment: @Pri which IDE you use ?

Comment: @Sagar007 Thank you Sagar. I used Eclipse, Intellij, Visual studio so far. When i cloned the project in Visual Studio IDE, the project couldn't be imported. So i want to know which IDE is best for Accessibility tests?

Comment: 'best' will depend on your needs.  I've listed options below.

Comment: The latest list for you reference: Automation Testing Tools for 2018
https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/best-automation-testing-tools-for-2018-top-10-reviews-8a4a19f664d2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start at the w3C site for accessibility: https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility

Review https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility.php for more details and then for tools review see https://www.w3.org/WAI/impl/software

Tools and website are listed at https://www.w3.org/WAI/eval/

Your most basic free tool is https://validator.w3.org/ where you can put in any public web address and get a report.  The hard part is that there will frequently be a lot of issues that are not important to you.  It can easily be 90% noise to 10% signal so you need to determine which issues that it reports are relevant for your business and your users.

I searched again for info in tools - turned out to be quite hard to separate out information that addresses usability of the tools themselves, by the developer, from usability of what the tools are building for use by end-users (what we are interested in), but here's what I found:

#### intelliJ Rubymine

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/JetBrains_ReSharper_VPAT.docx

#### Eclipse:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Accessibility/

#### ASP.NET - Visual Studio

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebAccessibilityChecker

You may also find the following tool useful:

https://www.deque.com/products/axe
*aXe is a free, open-source accessibility testing tool that runs right in your web browser.*

#### Screen Readers

[Standard for accessiblity testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/17048/8992)

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for this. These links gave me initial idea about accessibility tests. But i would like to know about the IDE too.

Comment: Added what I could find for IDE info

Answer (score 0):

There are many automation testing tools are there. Here are the sorted top 5 tools for your convenience. Reference URL: https://reqtest.com/testing-blog/automation-testing-tools/

Comment: Please disclose any affiliation you may have with the site you are linking. Also, please summarize the main points of the linked site in your answer.